# Joomla 1.5 & Indic Unicode Fonts - How-to?

Tags: unicode, joomla1.5

I am using Inscript Keyboard to directly type into TinyMCE. However when I click on save, all the characters appear as question marks on website and even in article list on admin side.
How I should solve the problem?

I am specifically talking about Marathi but the problem-solution might be same for all Devnagrari fonts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your output site UTF-8 encoded? Can you show a live example?

Comment: How can I check if the output site is UTF-8 encoded or not? I have checked the database collation via phpMyadmin. It was already set to UTF8_unicode_ci

Check this link for live example.
http://fillambazi.com/joomla/

Comment: Hi,
Solved.
Had to change collation of database through PhpMyAdmin.
Thanks.